# How to concatenate with href increment

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

This is the output i'm looking for

```
<a href="#value-1" title="name">link name</a>
<a href="#value-2" title="name">link name</a>
<a href="#value-3" title="name">link name</a>
```

I'm trying the below

```
<a>
<xsl:attribute name="href">"{concat('#value-',position())}"</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:value-of select="link name" />
</a>
```

I'm still not able to get the href value incremented. any pointers on how to have the href value incremented?

Comment: Can you show what your input XML looks like? Thanks!

Comment: Remember that `position()` only refers to the **current** node-set.

Comment: the xml is similar to this structure   . It does not have a valid url as its just used as expanding menu
<links-replicant>
            <link-name>google</ -link-name>
            <link-alttext>google</ -link-alttext>
            
  </links-replicant>

Comment: yes the whole xsl code is already inside a loop. The same works fine if I use 
  <a href="{concat('#value-',position())}"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="title" /></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use xsl:value-of here, in a similar manner to outputting "name"

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('#value-', position())" />
```

Alternatively use Attribute Value Templates, which is where the curly braces come in

```
<a href="#value-{position()}" name="{name}">
```

The curly braces only apply within attribute values.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. changing it to <xsl:value-of select="concat('#value-', position())" /> resolved the issue